# All the information is getting inside only in one block of excel python

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping

Hello I am new to the web scraping. I scrap a site but after I write it into the CSV only one block is filled with all the information and I want the information to be filled in row wise it will not matter if they are in single but they must be in different row.
Here is the code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import re
from csv import writer

url = 'https://virtualhs.pwcs.edu/about/faculty'
res = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content, 'lxml')
Title = soup.find('div', id='divContent')
if Title:
    for p in Title.select("p"):
        p.extract()
    for h2 in Title.select("h2"):
        h2.extract()
        Title =Title.text
        print(Title)
        with open('now.csv','w',encoding='utf-8', newline='') as f:
            thewriter = writer(f)
            thewriter.writerow([Title])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear what you are trying to scrape. Is it the teachers and the department?

If you use `'w'` as your parameter, it will overwrite after each iteration. You would need to use `'a'` to append after each iteration, but need to also make sure you write an initial "blank" csv to append to.

Personally, I think it's just easier to construct a dataframe, then write that to file:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://virtualhs.pwcs.edu/about/faculty'
res = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content, 'html.parser')
departments = soup.find_all('h3')

rows = []
for department in departments:
    for teacher in department.find_next('ul').find_all('li'):
        row = {
            'teacher':teacher.text,
            'department':department.text}
        rows.append(row)
    
df = pd.DataFrame(rows)
df.to_csv('now.csv', index=False)
```